# How to use password hashing with bcrypt in android java?

Tags: java, android, hash, bcrypt

I want to use bcrypt to hash the app password. But I could not get the result about use that in android java. How can I use bcrypt hashing in android?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626914/using-jbcrypt-to-salt-passwords-in-android-app-causes-a-long-hang

Comment: thank u @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java implementation of the BCrypt algorithm [here](https://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/), I even use a modified version of it in my [BCryptGenerator](https://github.com/dustinkredmond/bcrypt-generator) project.

Usage of the BCrypt class is as follows:

```
import com.whatever-domain.BCrypt


private String generateHashedPass(String pass) {
    // hash a plaintext password using the typical log rounds (10)
    return BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());
}

private boolean isValid(String clearTextPassword, String hashedPass) {
    // returns true if password matches hash
    return BCrypt.checkpw(clearTextPassword, hashedPass);
}
```